# How to convert tdata to telethon session?

Tags: python, api, telegram, telethon

I need to convert telegram data to telethon session.
How can i do this?
I tried to find a solution, spent three days, but I didn’t find anything

Comment: You'll have to look at how both formats work and then write the code to translate them

Comment: I understand, but I do not have enough experience to do this

Comment: looking for the same thing (session, api id and api hash to be precise), seems like the only way is to check telegram source code and parse the files the same way telegram does.

Answer (score 4):

It's been nearly two years, but there's now a Python library called [opentele](https://github.com/thedemons/opentele/) created to do this.

Assuming you already have Python knowledge, please follow the steps below.

#### First you need to install opentele from PyPi:

> pip install opentele

#### Preparing:

- You need to have a `tdata` folder that is already authorized (have at least one logged-in account).
- The default path to `tdata` folder on Windows is located at `%appdata%\Telegram Desktop\tdata`.
- Create a python (.py) file and import these things:

  ```py
  from opentele.td import TDesktop
  from opentele.tl import TelegramClient
  from opentele.api import API, UseCurrentSession, CreateNewSession
  import asyncio
  ```
- And you also need to put the main code inside an async function:

  ```py
  async def main():
      # PUT EXAMPLE CODE HERE

  asyncio.run(main())
  ```

### Initialize [TDesktop](https://opentele.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documentation/telegram-desktop/tdesktop/#class-tdesktop) from tdata folder

- Load the `tdata` folder into a `TDesktop` object:

  ```py
  # Load TDesktop client from tdata folder
  tdataFolder = r"C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Telegram Desktop\tdata"
  tdesk = TDesktop(tdataFolder)

  # Check if we have loaded any accounts
  assert tdesk.isLoaded()
  ```

### Converting [TDesktop](https://opentele.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documentation/telegram-desktop/tdesktop/#class-tdesktop) to [TelegramClient](https://opentele.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documentation/telethon/telegramclient/#class-telegramclient)

There are two ways you can do this, either by using the current session or creating (login to) a new session.

- Use the current session:

  ```py
  # flag=UseCurrentSession
  #
  # Convert TDesktop to Telethon using the current session.
  client = await tdesk.ToTelethon(session="telethon.session", flag=UseCurrentSession)
  ```
- Create a new session:

  ```py
  # flag=CreateNewSession
  #
  # Convert TDesktop to Telethon by creating a new session.
  # CreateNewSession will use the current session (in tdata folder) to authorize a new session using QR Login.
  # If 2FA is enabled for this account, you must specify the password via the password argument.
  # This is of course slower than UseCurrentSession.
  client = await tdesk.ToTelethon(session="telethon.session", flag=CreateNewSession)
  ```

### Connect and print all logged-in sessions.

```py
# Connect and print all logged-in sessions of this client.
# Telethon will save the session to telethon.session on creation.
await client.connect()
await client.PrintSessions()
```

### Final result example

```py
from opentele.td import TDesktop
from opentele.tl import TelegramClient
from opentele.api import API, UseCurrentSession
import asyncio

async def main():

    # Load TDesktop client from tdata folder
    tdataFolder = r"C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Telegram Desktop\tdata"
    tdesk = TDesktop(tdataFolder)
    
    # Check if we have loaded any accounts
    assert tdesk.isLoaded()

    # flag=UseCurrentSession
    #
    # Convert TDesktop to Telethon using the current session.
    client = await tdesk.ToTelethon(session="telethon.session", flag=UseCurrentSession)
    
    # Connect and print all logged-in sessions of this client.
    # Telethon will save the session to telethon.session on creation.
    await client.connect()
    await client.PrintSessions()

asyncio.run(main())
```

#### The result

- The session will be saved to `telethon.session` file.
- You can use this `telethon.session` with telethon, or use it directly with [opentele](https://github.com/thedemons/opentele/) - which is recommended because you don't need your own `API_ID` and `API_HASH`, the library by default will use Official Telegram API.

#### Remark

- [opentele](https://github.com/thedemons/opentele/) is a very well documented library, you can find its documentation [here](https://opentele.readthedocs.io/).
- It can also convert telethon sessions back to tdata and it's usable with Telegram Desktop.

#### Warning

- According to its docs, you must continue using the associated [API](https://opentele.readthedocs.io/en/develop/documentation/authorization/loginflag/#class-usecurrentsession) which you've had used to create that session whenever connecting to the server, or else you're at risk of losing that account.